# How to provide relation between a custom object and Opportunity Line Item?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have custom objects named Order and Order Line Item, just like Opportunity and Opportunity Line Item, they have same fields and relationships but Order Line Item has no need for Pricebook, products can be added directly. Also Order object has Lookup to Opportunity so every Order has a related Opportunity. What I need is when add a product to Order Line Item of the Order, same product must be added to Opportunity Line Item of the related Opportunity. I cannot give Lookup between Order Line Item and Opportunity Line Item, so don't know how get Opportunity, PriceBookEntryId values. I tried it in this trigger:

```
trigger CreateOpportunityProduct on Order_Line_Item__c(after insert, after update){
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OppLineList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(Order_Line_Item__c OrderLineObj : Trigger.new){
        OpportunityLineItem OppL = new OpportunityLineItem(
            Opportunity=OrderLineObj.?,  //Opportunity field is required but I don't know how to get it. 
            PricebookEntryId=OrderLineObj.Price_Book__c,  //I done a lookup named Price_Book__c to Price Book object but I don't know if it's helps.
            UnitPrice=OrderLineObj.UnitPrice__c,
            Quantity=OrderLineObj.Quantity__c
        );
        OppLineList.add(OppL);
    }
    if(OppLineList.size()>0)
        insert(OppLineList);
}
```

I write this trigger now but still having some errors, how can I make it run:

```
trigger CreateOpportunityProduct on Order_Line_Item__c(after insert, after update){   
if(trigger.isInsert){   
   List<ID> pricebookID=new List<ID>();
   List<ID> opportunityID=new List<ID>();  
List<OpportunityLineItem> newopportunitylineitemlist=new List< OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(Order_Line_Item__c orderlist: Trigger.new){
OpportunityLineItem Oppitem=new OpportunityLineItem();
Oppitem.Quantity=orderlist.Quantity__c;
Oppitem.UnitPrice=orderlist.UnitPrice__c;
pricebookID.add(Oppitem.PriceBookEntryId); //Error: Compile Error: Invalid field PriceBookEntryId for SObject Order_Line_Item__c at line 11 column 17
opportunityID.add(Oppitem.OpportunityId); //Error: Compile Error: Invalid field OpportunityId for SObject Order_Line_Item__c at line 12 column 19
newopportunitylineitemlist.add(Oppitem);}
List<Order__c> orderlist= new List<Order__c>([Select Id,Opportunities__c From Order__c Where Opportunities__c IN:opportunityID]);   
List<PricebookEntry> pricebookentrylist = new List<PricebookEntry>([Select Id,Product2Id From PricebookEntry Where Id IN:pricebookID]); 
if(newopportunitylineitemlist.size()>0)
insert(newopportunitylineitemlist);}
}
```

Comment: Spring 14 has a new Order object, You may want to take a look at that if you are still in the implementation phase. https://org62.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_orders_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: I know, but Order object here must be custom object.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you were aware that there was some standard functionality coming very soon that might solve some of your issues.

Comment: @DanielHoechst - have you just exposed your SF domain? `na1`, `eu1` or `login` would work equally well...

Comment: @eyescream, I must have been logged into Salesforce's main org when I grabbed that link. I'm in a customer chatter group there.

Comment: The [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brfa) to allow opportunity product (OpportunityLineItem) records to be a lookup field is currently [in the IDXR voting round until the 22nd of Sep](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004Y3dDi).

Answer (score 8):

You cant' make a lookup to OpportunityLineItem. Best you could do is some Text(18) field filled in with triggers. You could make the lookup from Opp Line Item to Order Line Item but it'd look bit stupid (Order -> Opportunity but Opp LI -> Ord LI).

Nonetheless - a rough idea how to fetch Opps because that's a start anyway:

1. Fetch Orders related to line items from current trigger's scope.

   ```
   Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
   for(Order_Line_Item__c oli : trigger.new){
       orderIds.add(oli.Order__c);
   }
   ```
2. Fetch Opportunities (and Pricebook selections on them) that these Orders point to. Consult http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm to understand the relations

   ```
   Map<Id, Order__c> ordersMap = new Map<Id, Order__c>([SELECT Id, Name,
       Opportunity__c, Opportunity__r.Pricebook2Id
       FROM Order__c
       WHERE Id IN :orderIds]);
   ```
3. To create an Opp Line Item you need Opportunity Id:

   ```
   for(Order_Line_Item__c oli : trigger.new){
      Id oppId = ordersMap.get(oli.Order__c).Opportunity__c;
      ...
   }
   ```
4. and PricebookEntryId (I'm skipping the price, quantity etc). That one will be tricky because we don't know what do you have on the line items? Lookup to Product2? What do people actually fill in? You said you've made a lookup to pricebook, but it might be bit of duplicate info (the pricebook entry you'll end up picking has to match the opportunity's pricebook or the line won't save). You will need a query similar to this:

   ```
   SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id,Product2Id
   FROM PricebookEntry
   WHERE Pricebook2Id = :ordersMap.get(oli.Order__c).Opportunity__r.Pricebook2Id
   AND Product2Id = :oli.Product__c
   ```

Of course if you'll store say product names on Order line items, you could go `... AND Product2.Name = 'Generator'` in that last line. You might also get multiple entries for that product in the pricebook if you have multiple currencies for example...

Up to you how to go from here...

Comment: Thanks. How can I use your codes in my trigger? Order object has lookup only to Opportunity(Opportunities__c). Order Line Item has lookup to Order(Order__c),Product(Product2__c) and Pricebook(Price_Book__c). Those are enough or do I need any other relationships? And what is Opportunity__r in your code?

Comment: `Opportunity__r` is a way to access fields from Opportunity to which Order__c.Opportunity__c field will point. If you've never seen "dots" in Salesforce queries - they're bit like JOIN constructions from normal databases. Compare with `SELECT Account.Name, Account.Owner.Name FROM Contact` and check http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: I want to use your codes but cant use them with my trigger, can you help with the making trigger? I posted a new trigger, can you help me to place your codes in that trigger please because I tried and get errors.

Comment: Does your company use Currencies?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand.

Comment: What do you see if you go to setup and type "Manage currencies" in the search? Do you have "Currency" field visible on pretty much every object (standard & custom), the field would be a picklist with currency codes (USD, CAD, GBP, CHF etc) and the field API Name is always `CurrencyIsoCode`. If you have no idea I guess your organisation doesn't use them, everything displays in one currency everywhere?

Comment: I searched for Manage currencies, and nothing found.

Comment: I'm bit busy at work at the moment, will try to write up something more in the evening (~6 hrs from now)

Comment: I solved the problem, no need for that, thank you.

Comment: Cool, congratulations! If you want you can post & accept your own answer so in future maybe somebody else will benefit?